# Javascript Converting Ints to Time?

Tags: javascript

For a project app I'm making, a homework keeper, I need to be able to turn a number like 10 into a month like october, then do this with year, month, day, and time. Then I need to save it all in a date. How do I do this? I have been looking everywhere and cannot find how to do it.

Comment: JavaScript does not have facilities to turn a number into words, and has limited formatting capabilities. You'll have to do that yourself or use a library like https://momentjs.com/.

Comment: What u looking for?    Input and expected output

Comment: Check out Javascript date constructor, `new Date(2017, 10, 2, 12, 45, 35);`

Comment: what result do you expect for `2017`?

Comment: @HassanImam that would be November (11th month) as `Date` months start with 0.

Comment: Yes, because month are 0 based in Javascript. It was an example as how to use numeric value to get date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [the Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```
var month = 10;
var day = 17;
var year = 2017;
var hour = 8;//Use the 24 hour clock for times in the PM
var minutes = 36;

var date = new Date(year, month-1, day, hour, minutes);//Outputs October 17th, 2017 at 8:36am in your local timezone
```

You have to subtract 1 from the month because January starts at 0, not 1.

Alternatively, I like to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) for the flexibility depending on use, so you could instantiate it like this:

```
var date = moment(year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes, 'YYYY-M-D H:m');//Because you are using numbers/integers, none of them will have preceding zeroes
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor - I think it doesn everything you need.

Your biggest gotcha is that months are 0-indexed so you'll actually turn `9` into October. Also beware that if you don't initialise `Date` with anything, it'll assume you mean now.

```
var date = new Date();
date; // -> Tue Oct 17 2017 13:34:49 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
date.setMonth(10); // -> 1510925689970
date; // -> Fri Nov 17 2017 13:34:49 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```